# jq combine fields from array of objects in 2 json files into 3rd json file

Tags: json, command-line, terminal, jq

## file1.json

```
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  },
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  }
]
```

## file2.json

```
[
  {
    "c": "c"
  },
  {
    "c": "c"
  }
]
```

## desired output: file3.json

```
[
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c"
  },
  {
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c"
  }
]
```

Comment: Just an FYI: In this case there will be identical number of objects in both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problem, `transpose` (think `zip`) can often be used to produce compact solutions.  In the present case:

```
jq -s 'transpose | map(add)' file1.json file2.json
```

jq's `transpose` can also be used with arrays that are not of the same length.